# Android WebView Stops while clicking Back

Tags: android, webview

My `webview` module isn't working. Whenever I try to navigate back from any webpage, the app crashes giving following error

```
 "Unfortunately the app has stopped".
```

Can anyone please explain what is the reason?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WebView myWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadUrl("http://nahdaschools.com/v4/index.php/apps");
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView.copyBackForwardList().getCurrentIndex() > 0) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        // Your exit alert code, or alternatively line below to finish
        super.onBackPressed(); // finishes activity
    }
}}
```

Comment: dude where's my stacktrace!!

Comment: @goonerDroid [here](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg) :D

Comment: can you show us your stacktrace? Maybe copyBackForwardList() returns null and you are trying to get the current index on a null object?

Answer (score 0):

with this you will be able to come on your last activity.

```
     @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed(); 
           moveTaskToBack(false);// finishes activity
         }   

 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

     if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
         switch(keyCode)
         {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
         if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
              myWebView.goBack();
        }
       else{
             finish();
          }
            return true;
        }

         }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
           }
```